# How can I store and execute the command "export PATH=$PREFIX/bin" from a script?

Tags: bash, shell, export

I would like to write a script that has several commands of the kind

```
> export PATH=$PREFIX/bin
```

Where

```
> $PREFIX = /home/usr
```

or something else. Instead of typing it into the the Shell (/bin/bash) I would run the script to execute the commands.

Tried it with sh and then with a .py script having the line,

```
> commands.getstatusoutput('export PATH=$PREFIX/bin')
```

but these result into the error "bad variable name". 
Would be thankful for some ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad variable name is probably just a complaint that `$PREFIX` is undefined.

Usually a setting of `PATH` would look something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new/path/to/programs
```

so that you retain the old `PATH` but add something onto the end.

You are best off putting such things in your `.bashrc` so that they get run every time you log in.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to adjust PATH (or any other environment variable) via a script after your `.profile` and equivalents have been run, you need to 'dot' or 'source' the file containing the script:

```
. file_setting_path
source file_setting_path
```

The `.` notation applies to all Bourne shell derivatives, and is standardized by POSIX.  The `source` notation is used in C shell and has infected Bash completely unnecessarily.

Note that the file (`file_setting_path`) can be specified as a pathname, or if it lives in a directory listed on `$PATH`, it will be found.  It only needs to be readable; it does not have to be executable.

The way the dot command works is that it reads the named file as part of the current shell environment, rather than executing it in a sub-shell like a normal script would be executed.  Normally, the sub-shell sets its environment happily, but that doesn't affect the calling script.